# Focus does not stay inside the PrimeNG <p-dialog> component

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, primeng

I have been using PrimeNG in the project.
I came across one issue regarding the focus of the
p-dialog component.
Even in the example given in PrimeNG website we are able to reproduce this issue.
e.g. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog
Steps to reproduce this:

1. Click on the 'show' button
2. Press 'Tab' on the keyboard.

You can see the focus is lost and goes to the back screen.
Now I have tried using `modal` attribute provided in the document with the values `modal` or `true`.

Anybody has faced this issue? Is there anything that I am missing?
When the dialog opens, how should I keep and restrict the focus on the dialog and not on the back screen?

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/4544 https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/4541 There is also some fix https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/4686 but it is not in release yet

Comment: I have tries these but still does not work...

Answer (score 2):

Use `onShow()` of primeng dialog and in that function use queryselector to select the dom element as HTMLElement and call focus() function. Ex:

```
onShow() {
    (document.querySelector('input[name="time"]') as HTMLElement).focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PrimeNG team has fixed this issue in v7 and above.

May check the same link mentioned above: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog